# Data substring not showing full value

Tags: vb.net

My code should be showing 32 characters but it's only showing 7. This is the code I currently have:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Property sr As Object

    Private Sub BrowseBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BrowseBtn.Click

        OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()

        FilePathLabel.Text = OpenFileDialog.FileName

    End Sub

    Private Sub SearchBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchBtn.Click

        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog.FileName)

        Dim data = sr.ReadToEnd()

        Dim pos = data.IndexOfAny("LASTSAVE")
        If pos >= 0 Then

        End If

        CatiaVersionLabel.Text = data.Substring(pos, 32)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Not too sure why it's doing this as the text that needs to be found is there when I open it independently.

Comment: My first piece of advice is to turn on Option Strict. My second is what are the values of the different variables as the code progresses?

Comment: thank you, the only main variable is the file name itself when located, once located it just needs to locate the upto 32 characters after the word "LASTSAVE" which is persons name and a date

Comment: Use `IndexOf` instead of `IndexOfAny`.  If it doesn't find the string, it will return -1.  `sr` as a Property Object and a local StreamReader looks problematic.  Get rid of both, and just use `File.ReadAllText()`.  I would think you would want to read the file in the FilePathLabel.Text property,

Comment: One other thing to remember is that pos will be the index at the beginning of "LASTSAVE", which means you'll have to offset pos by the length of "LASTSAVE". If you still have problems add a sample of the file to your post.